# Neo4j-ogm "Filter" to search an parent entity by some of parent property and its child property

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {
    private Long id,
    private String email,
    @Relationship(type = "hasOne", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Profile profile
}

@NodeEntity
    public class Profile {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName
}
```

I just need to load `user` objects where `email = "abc"` and `firstName="xyz"`.

I am using spring-data-neo4j 4.2.3.RELEASE.

How effectively use ogm filter on this query (I dont need native query)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the nested Filters as following: 

    `Filter emailFilter = new Filter("email", ComparisonOperator.EQUALS, "krishna@abc.in");
    Filter firstNameFilter = new Filter("firstName", ComparisonOperator.EQUALS, "krishna");
    firstNameFilter.setNestedPath({
        new Filter.NestedPathSegment("profile", Profile.class);
    });
    return session.loadAll(User.class, emailFilter.and(firstNameFilter));`

Comment: its useful answer. just need to remove unnecessary brackets {  }  while initializing NestedPathSegment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Data [derived finders](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#_queries_derived_from_finder_method_names).

In your `UserRepository` create a method like this:

```
User findByEmailAndProfileFirstName(String email, String firstName);
```

Note that you can use only 1 level of nesting in derived finders.

Comment: yep.. thanks.. I suppose to write native query only even i create a method like this in UserRepository using @Query right?. OGM is offering "Filter".  How to use filter?